# Is there any Javascript framework that supports an interface like the Viewing pane in Yahoo!Mail Inbox with a preview panel below?

Tags: javascript, interface, yahoo, inbox, preview-pane

Apologies if this is a too basic question but I couldn't find any satisfactory answer in Google. I'm not sure if there is any open-sourced framework
that provide the interface like Yahoo!Mail Inbox? To be more specific, I'd need a pane that shows a listing of items on top (and the items are sortable, draggable...), and when a user click on an item, the content will be displayed in the "Preview pane" below. (screenshot attached).

Thanks a lot for any hints or pointers on where to start.!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiISR.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo!Mail was written with help of YUI, and as I see they used old one [version](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/2/) (2.7.0).With help of FireBug I see that Yahoo~Mail has "package" YAHOO.mail, probably it contains scripts needed to process mail box, but it is not a part of YUI. Anyway I'm not sure that you want is part of any library because this is related to business logic of your application... With YUI you will get pane which you need, but there is no "preview", this is what you need to develop. But that's easy - when user clicks anyway you can load appropriate content into the area with preview; framework will give you utility functions for it (ajax, DOM scripting), so it won't take much time.

There is a nice [example](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/layout/adv_layout_source.html) of what can you do using YUI, just investigate it, it does what you are asking about.

Comment: Thanks Maxym, the example is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo uses the YUI javascript framework: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/